# HP 6125XLG switch in IRF not passing traffic on standby switch

Tags: switch, hp, hp-comware, irf

I have HP 6125XLG switches in HP c7000 chassis. I have setup for IRF config (similar to Cisco vPC). I have configured all my blades in LACP active-active and everything works fine. But one of blade I want to configure for SRIOV interface which doesn't support bonding so I have configured both blade 10G interface without LACP bond and noticed port connected to standby 6125XLG switch not passing traffic but port connected to Master IRF switch passing traffic.

is this normal behavior?

[image]

If I configure IP address on `eno49` port then I can ping gateway or any IP outside world. But if I configure ip on `eno50` then I can't ping.

I have similar VLAN configured on both port and everything is identical. Server is connected to `port 8` on both switches

```
#
 sysname sw-enc-101-1-a
#
 irf mac-address persistent timer
 irf auto-update enable
 undo irf link-delay
 irf member 1 priority 32
 irf member 2 priority 30
#

#
irf-port 1/1
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/17
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/19
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
#
irf-port 2/2
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/17
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/18
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/19
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/20
#

#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/8
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 9 to 15 99 101
 port trunk pvid vlan 99
#
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/8
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 9 to 15 99 101
 port trunk pvid vlan 99
#
```

IRF setting

```
<sw-enc-101-1-a>display irf
MemberID    Role    Priority  CPU-Mac         Description
 *+1        Master  32        00e0-fc0f-8c02  ---
   2        Standby 30        00e0-fc0f-8c03  ---
--------------------------------------------------
 * indicates the device is the master.
 + indicates the device through which the user logs in.

 The bridge MAC of the IRF is: d894-03e5-6ff8
 Auto upgrade                : yes
 Mac persistent              : 6 min
 Domain ID                   : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

IRF basically tells the switches to act like a single chassis. The two ports that you connect the host to are just two switch ports.

Forwarding to them is entirely based on the MAC address(es) they show towards the stack. If the host uses them as a pair, then they need to be configured in the same way, which you did.

Essentially, everything is up to the host: if it uses different MACs (and likely IP addresses) on both ports, that also controls the traffic from the switch.

If it uses just a single MAC that needs to move to the secondary port when the primary link fails - in that case you'd see no traffic on the secondary port as long as the primary is active. I'd test functionality by shifting port priority on the host (which is off topic here).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try to debug and see what I am missing